# Serializing XML With Same Element Name

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have been having some trouble serializing the following XML...

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sap sap2010 sads" x:Class="Main"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"
 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 xmlns:sco="clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<TextExpression.NamespacesForImplementation>
    <sco:Collection x:TypeArguments="x:String">
      <x:String>System.Activities</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Activities.Statements</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Activities.Expressions</x:String>
    </sco:Collection>
</TextExpression.NamespacesForImplementation>
<TextExpression.ReferencesForImplementation>
    <sco:Collection x:TypeArguments="AssemblyReference">
      <AssemblyReference>System.Activities</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>Microsoft.VisualBasic</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>mscorlib</AssemblyReference>
    </sco:Collection>
</TextExpression.ReferencesForImplementation>
</Activity>
```

I have created the following classes to serialize the first `<TextExpression.NamespacesForImplementation>` element and created similar classes to serialize the `<TextExpression.ReferencesForImplementation>` which work individually...

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities")]
    public class Activity
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Ignorable", Namespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006")]
        public string Ignorable { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Class", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml")]
        public string Class { get; set; }

        [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
        public XmlSerializerNamespaces Xmlns { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TextExpression.NamespacesForImplementation", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities")]
        public NamespacesForImplementation NamespacesForImplementation { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TextExpression.ReferencesForImplementation", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities")]
        public ReferencesForImplementation ReferencesForImplementation { get; set; }
    }

public class NamespacesForImplementation
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Collection", Namespace = "clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=mscorlib")]
    public StringCollection Collection { get; set; }
}

public class ReferencesForImplementation
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Collection", Namespace = "clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=mscorlib")]
    public ReferencesCollection Collection { get; set; }
}

public class StringCollection
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TypeArguments", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml")]
    public string TypeArguments { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "String", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml")]
    public List<string> String { get; set; }
}

public class ReferencesCollection
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TypeArguments", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml")]
    public string TypeArguments { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AssemblyReference", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml")]
    public List<string> AssemblyReference { get; set; }
}
```

The above XML is valid with appropriate namespaces. The issue arises when attempting to serialize both `Collection` elements, since they both have different inner elements but have the same element name. Any suggestions? I should also mention I have tried using the special paste option 'XML to C#' in Visual Studio 2017, but the result captured does not provide the input result once serialized and deserialized immediately after.

Comment: Where is the closing tag for Activity?  It is missing so the xml is not valid.

Comment: @jdweng Apologies, this was added to the original post but didn't appear after posting. I have amended this now.

Comment: Where is class ReferencesForImplementation?

Comment: @jdweng I will add this to the original post too! Thank you for the post improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need for each property in a class a value when serializing.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Activity activity = new Activity() {
                Ignorable = "sap sap2010 sads",
                Class = "Main",
                NamespacesForImplementation = new NamespacesForImplementation() {
                    Collection = new StringCollection() {
                        TypeArguments = "x:String",
                        String = new List<string>() {
                            "System.Activities", "System.Activities.Statements", "System.Activities.Expressions"
                        }
                    }
                },
                ReferencesForImplementation = new ReferencesForImplementation() {
                    Collection = new StringCollection() {
                        TypeArguments = "AssemblyReference",
                        AssemblyReference = new List<string>() {
                            "System.Activities", "Microsoft.VisualBasic", "mscorlib"
                        }
                    }
                }

            };

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Activity));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, activity);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities")]
    public class Activity
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Ignorable", Namespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006")]
        public string Ignorable { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Class", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml")]
        public string Class { get; set; }

        [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
        public XmlSerializerNamespaces Xmlns { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TextExpression.NamespacesForImplementation", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities")]
        public NamespacesForImplementation NamespacesForImplementation { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TextExpression.ReferencesForImplementation", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities")]
        public ReferencesForImplementation ReferencesForImplementation { get; set; }
    }

    public class NamespacesForImplementation
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Collection", Namespace = "clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=mscorlib")]
        public StringCollection Collection { get; set; }
    }
    public class ReferencesForImplementation
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Collection", Namespace = "clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=mscorlib")]
        public StringCollection Collection { get; set; }
    }

    public class StringCollection
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TypeArguments", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml")]
        public string TypeArguments { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "String", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml")]
        public List<string> String { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AssemblyReference", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml")]
        public List<string> AssemblyReference { get; set; }
    }
}
```